# Repeat the macro if the button is stil pressed

Tags: excel, winapi, vba

Is it possible, using Excel-VBA and/or Windows API, repeat the macro of a button by just holding that button pressed?

In my personal case, I want to simulate those little black arrows spotted in the corners of the screen, that we use to navigate through our Excel sheet.
Using the macro recorder, I found the code to do that, but I have to press the button each time I need the macro to work. I would like to hold the button and see the sheet moving until I unpress the button, just like those arrows.

The code I am using is as follows, for the four arrows:

```
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=1
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-1
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=1
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-1
```

Comment: When you say "press the button", do you mean a key on your keyboard? Because if you're scrolling won't you eventually scroll away from the button you're trying to hold down?

Comment: Sorry for my missing. The buttons are in the ribbon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - use an ActiveX SpinButton or Scrollbar instead of a button.  (This *also* gives you the ability to click the other button to go the other way)

```
Option Explicit
Dim lSpinButton As Long 'So we know of you are spinning up or down

Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
    If SpinButton1.Value < lSpinButton Then
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=1
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=1
    Else
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Up:=1
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToLeft:=1
    End If
    lSpinButton = SpinButton1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: What a great news to start my day. Thank you! I need to use those arrows a lot, but they are too far away from each other that it becomes a pain in the end of the day.

Comment: If you hold down middle-click on the mouse, then you can just drag around.  Or, press turn on [Scroll Lock], and use the Arrow keys